# How does Dee Raain use the Mirrors to highlight negative human traits in the poem "Mirror of Truth"?

Tags: poetry, meaning, symbolism

The poem "Mirror of Truth" by Dee Raain is as follows:

> What is seen in the mirror is nothing more than a person with lies and hate.
>   With sadness and traits
>   Of discrimination and disgrace.
>
> What I see is a broken face of sadness.
>   With no hope to be filled with gladness.
>   More than can ever resent.
>   To have a heart broken and bent.
>
> What I see in the mirror is someone who lost.
>   At the price of being cost.
>   With losing someone they love.
>   And being hurt so bad, it hurts to see them gone.
>
> What I see in the mirror
>   Is me. The 'I am' and may have already became to be.
>   This is who I am and how part of my life is.
>   And unlike most for me this is the mirror of truth.

---

- In the above poem, how does the poet use mirrors to highlight negative emotions of humans?
- Is the author describing just himself, or humanity as a whole?
- Also, is it right to think that in the last stanza, he is accepting his weaknesses, providing a positive touch to the poem?